# string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace equivalent in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and wanted to find the equivalent of [C# string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1) in python. With my limited web search, I created the below function

```
def isNullOrWhiteSpace(str):
  return not str or not str.strip()  

print "Result: " + isNullOrWhiteSpace("Test")
print "Result: " + isNullOrWhiteSpace(" ")
#print "Result: " + isNullOrWhiteSpace() #getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'mp$length' of undefined
```

But this is printing

```
Result: undefined
Result: undefined
```

I wanted to try how it would behave if no value is passed. Unfortunately, I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mp$length' of undefined` for the commented line. Can someone help with these situations I need to handle?

Comment: This looks like JavaScript. This doesn't seem to be Python and I think `mp$length` is a syntax error, and there's no undefined in python

Comment: I was testing it in https://www.guru99.com/execute-python-online.html. I am not sure why a javascript error is thrown there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the follwoing using `isspace`:

```
>>> tests = ['foo', ' ', '\r\n\t', '', None]
>>> [not s or s.isspace() for s in tests]
[False, True, True, True, True]
```

> str.isspace()
>
> Return true if there are only whitespace characters in the string and
> there is at least one character, false otherwise.

An empty function call is not like passing `None` to it, so you can set a default value for this specific case.

In your case something like:

```
def isNullOrWhiteSpace(str=None):
  return not str or str.isspace()

print("Result: ", isNullOrWhiteSpace("Test"))  #False
print("Result: ", isNullOrWhiteSpace(" "))  #True 
print("Result: ", isNullOrWhiteSpace())  #True
```